# Bootstrap 2.3 CSS Responsive left with a white space on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm creating a website (and I'm a noob at this). I'm working on the functionality portion of design and i'll have someone do graphics later.

Currently when it goes into responsive (mobile view) it leaves a 2px margin on the right that is movable on a mobile browser (and scrollable). I can't for the life of me get rid of that.

if I turn on overflow-x: hidden, then it does become non scrollable but still movable.

I want that extra space to go away. I don't see it defined as padding in any of the css.

Using Bootstrap 2.3

Comment: I've encountered the same problem, it had something to do with the navbar.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Solved by adding this to my custom css:

```
html, body {
  width: auto !important;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Note: the [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is only being used so it takes priority over other CSS. Most instances will not need `!important` if you load your custom CSS after your bootstrap CSS.

Comment: for other's references: you don't neccesarily need to add `!important` if you do not override this anywhere else.

Comment: This makes the scroll bar disappear but, unless it's just me, if you click and drag a selection to the right you can see that the gap is still there. Doesn't seem like a real fix. I've always noticed that damn gap when using Bootstrap... don't think I've ever found a perfect solution :/

Comment: I think it only applies to you because the gap on my page is gone!

Comment: This creates issues with links referencing segments inside the page. It seems like they stop functioning when you add these rules.

Comment: You saved me from death. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm super late to the game here but I figured out why this happens in the first place.
If you're using a navbar, there's some extra padding in the navbar-right element that shouldn't be there. It has a margin-right of 15px that causes this gap. Overwrite it and problem solved!

Comment: She is right. This is much better solution than the one that is accepted and have million upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried doing this, but it worked only on browser based mobile emulators. It also works nicely when I resize my browser.

But, when I check it on my phone - Samsung Galaxy S2 & iPhone 5, it still shows me the white space.

I also tried:

```
@media handheld and (max-width: 481px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  html,body{width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;}
}

@media handheld and (max-width: 380px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  html,body{width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;}
}
```

Comment: If you're using bootstrap 3.x, then no... this is the wrong solution... one of your containers isn't really "contained".

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.container` class with `.container-fluid` in body and in your *.css file* make the `padding right and left : 0px;`
 That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-left, margin-right

And change

```
    <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner navbar-fixed-top">
```

to

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">`
```

Comment: That seemed to make things worse while resizing and no change in the end result

Comment: I think I saw navbar-inner's margin-left, margin-right set to -20px, then they disappeared

Comment: actually the screen is still movable to the side on a mobile device. so now we have 2 issues instead of one

Comment: I've done some manual adjustments on the css and still have like a 2px  white space on the right side. even though everything is declared a min of 385 (html, body, nav, etc)

Comment: It still slightly scrolls to the left on the iPhone (at least on the iPhone 5)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply wrapping the .row in another .container-fluid class element. This should take care of the margin.

Comment: This was for bootstrap 2.x, you're referring to bootstrap 3.x which  out of the box works a lot better